# webrequest via webhdfs with data node failover

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-2.7.2

i have hadoop cluster with hadoop version  apache 2.7.1

that is high available and  consists of five nodes

mn1 ,mn2 ,dn1,dn2,dn3

if we are  accesing wbhdfs from browser to open afile  called myfile that has replication factor = 3 
and exits on dn1,dn2 and dn3

we issue the following command from browser

```
http://mn1:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN
```

so mn1 redirects this request as a result to dn1 or dn2 or dn3 
and we get the file

and we can get the file too from hadoop by the following command

```
hdfs dfs -cat /hadoophome/myfile
```

but in the case of data nodes failure (suppose that dn1 and dn3 are down now)

if we issue the commnad

```
hdfs dfs -cat /hadoophome/myfile
```

we can retrieve the file

but if we issue webhdfs command from browser and this is my state

```
http://mn1:50070/webhdfs/v1/hadoophome/myfile/?user.name=root&op=OPEN
```

mn1 will redirect the request to dn1 or dn3 which are dead and some times it redirects the request to dn2 and i can retrieve the file

shouldn't mn1 redirect webhdfs request to alive data nodes only
how to handle this error
should it be handled from application ?

Answer (score 0):

edit  hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.heartbeat.recheck-interval</name>
    <value>10000</value>
</property>
```

where this property is measured in milliseconds

and you will get a timeout of 50 seconds

because 
default  value for heartbeat.interval is 3 seconds

and Timeout to consider data node as dead

```
 2 * heartbeat.recheck.interval + 10 * heartbeat.interval
```

so 
timeout= 2 * (10 second) + 10 * 3 second = 50 second